# Java Text Encryption for Multiple Unknown Recipients

Tags: java, encryption, messaging

I have an application working fine with shared public/secret private keys for encrypting arbitrary large text strings.

I am using BouncyCastle with

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
private static final int KEY_SIZE = 2048;
```

So using Bob and Annie as example

Annie and Bob share each others public keys...

Annie can send Bob an encrypted message using Bobs public key to encrypt her message. With Bob happily decrypt ing using his private key.

Bob can reply with a message encrypted with Annies public key.

However, how does Annie send an encrypted message to an Unknown recipient?

How could Annie "publish" a message to a List of Unknown recipients?

Is this possible?

Comment: Since RSA is public key cryptography, it means that she would have to have each of her recipient's public keys to send an encrypted message to each of them invidivually... Which is OK since she only needs the recipients's public keys. I'm not sure what your question is about? Is this about encrypting outgoing messages or non repudiation?

Comment: @fge I am trying to develop a messaging application, that's a mix of publish/subscribe and chat room. I wanted the messages at rest too be encrypted. If using RSA means I have to distribute public keys to "everyone", is there an alternative approach for encrypting text?

Comment: Hey, _that is_ the core principle of public key cryptography; you can distribute your public key in the wild as long as you keep your private key secret. If you have the public key of some entity E, you use E's public key to encrypt the message you want to send; once it is encrypted, only E's private key can decrypt it and, how convenient, only E has the private key! That is how public cryptograpy _works_.

Comment: Only solution I see is that you assume that unknown reciepients are part of a group. You could have a "group" private key that everybody in the group has. The other solution is like in mail programs. If you send to a group, you really resolve the group to concrete addresses, and you have the public key for every one of them. You then send one encripted message to each address. However, it would be easier if you could provide more info on your requirement, as this scenario will cause people to give the simplest solutions... :) What restrictions do you have?

Comment: @Martin The wrinkle with my application is that when I send the messages I don't know the recipients will be, as I send my messages to a location not a user, so there's no way of knowing the public keys off the actual recipients of my message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really sent anything to somebody without knowing at least *one* thing about them. That one thing doesn't have to be the public key. It can be something else.

RSA and EC-based counterparts are not the only player in the asymmetric encryption realm.

- **Identity-based Encryption** (IBE) enables anyone to encrypt something for somebody knowing only their "identity" which is a simple string. For many people their identity is tightly coupled with their e-mail address, so you can use that. Of course, it doesn't have to be. It only needs to be a unique string.

  A trusted third party would later check the identity of a client that applies for their private key and if the identity matches, it would generate the private key for decryption. I'm sure there are IBE implementation in Java around somewhere considering how long it is already around.

  A problem with IBE is that you still might need to send many messages to each and every intended recipient.
- **Attribute-based Encryption** (ABE) is better in that regard, because you can encrypt some plaintext with a policy (in the Attribute-based Access Control sense) and it can be only decrypted if the recipient holds the necessary attribute secret keys. This is called Ciphertext-policy ABE. [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/what-is-attribute-based-encryption) is a little more detailed description.

  You still need a trusted third party, but now you can easily encrypt for groups based on attributes. The private key generation can happen at a later time than the encryption. The [JCPABE](https://github.com/TU-Berlin-SNET/JCPABE) library is written in Java and works completely in Java. It is based on jPBC, but it can be sped up when additionally installing libpbc which is the original C-version.

Comment: Attribute-based Encryption (ABE) sounds very interesting

Answer (score 1):

By the principles of public-key cryptography, Annie is unable to publish an encrypted message to a set of technically unknown recipients. She must have their public key (certificate) available.

You or your application does not have to be responsible for key management, so long as trusted third party certificate authority and registration authorities can manage them. If that is feasible in your environment, you'd at most have to perform path validation on each public key certificate but not directly manage the material.

Comment: Nice idea, I hadn't thought of using a third party to make the keys/certificates, are there any free options?

Comment: Yeah, there's actually a few. [OpenCA](https://pki.openca.org/) and [Dogtag](http://pki.fedoraproject.org/wiki/PKI_Main_Page) are good options. They all come with some degree of a learning curve, and have some setup costs, but that's inherent with employing good security regardless, and it sounds like you're already on board for it.